# js constructor function

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня был объект который я создавал без конструктора т.к. в этом не было нужды (он использовался в одном экземпляре). В процессе написания кода появились точно такие же объекты и дабы избежать дубляжа кода, решил создать конструктор для моего "начального" объекта.

Вот код моего начального объекта :

```
var documents = {
data : [],
btnTitle : "ADD ALL",
numberOfSelected: 0,
addOrRemoveAll : function() {
    var status = documents.numberOfSelected < documents.data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < documents.data.length; i++) {
        if(status && documents.data[i].checked == false) {
            documents.data[i].checked = true;
            documents.numberOfSelected += 1;
            attachedLinks.addData(documents.data[i]);
        }
        if(!status && documents.data[i].checked == true){
            documents.data[i].checked = false;
            documents.numberOfSelected -= 1;
            for (var key in  attachedLinks.data) {
                if(attachedLinks.data[key].kindOf == 0){
                    attachedLinks.data.splice(key, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    documents.updateTitle();
},
updateNumberOfSelected: function(event, element){
    if(documents.data[element.index].checked){
        documents.numberOfSelected += 1;
        attachedLinks.addData(documents.data[element.index]);
    }
    else{
        documents.numberOfSelected -= 1;
        for (var key in  attachedLinks.data) {
            if(attachedLinks.data[key].id == documents.data[element.index].id && attachedLinks.data[key].kindOf == 0){
                attachedLinks.data.splice(key, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    documents.updateTitle();
},
updateTitle: function(){
    if(documents.numberOfSelected < documents.data.length){
        documents.btnTitle = "ADD ALL";
    }
    else{
        documents.btnTitle = "REMOVE ALL";
    }
    attachedLinks.update();
}
};
```

Такой конструктор я написал :

```
function DataList(data){
this.data = data;
this.btnTitle = "ADD ALL";
this.numberOfSelected = 0;
this.addOrRemoveAll = function() {
    var status = this.numberOfSelected < this.data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        if(status && this.data[i].checked == false) {
            this.data[i].checked = true;
            this.numberOfSelected += 1;
            attachedLinks.addData(this.data[i]);
        }
        if(!status && this.data[i].checked == true){
            this.data[i].checked = false;
            this.numberOfSelected -= 1;
            for (var key in  attachedLinks.data) {
                if(attachedLinks.data[key].kindOf == 0){
                    attachedLinks.data.splice(key, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.updateTitle();
};
this.updateNumberOfSelected = function(event, element){
    if(this.data[element.index].checked){
        this.numberOfSelected += 1;
        attachedLinks.addData(this.data[element.index]);
    }
    else{
        this.numberOfSelected -= 1;
        for (var key in  attachedLinks.data) {
            if(attachedLinks.data[key].id == this.data[element.index].id && attachedLinks.data[key].kindOf == 0){
                attachedLinks.data.splice(key, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    this.updateTitle();
};
this.updateTitle = function(){
    if(this.numberOfSelected < this.data.length){
        this.btnTitle = "ADD ALL";
    }
    else{
        this.btnTitle = "REMOVE ALL";
    }
    attachedLinks.update();
};
}
```

и так создал экземпляр объекта :

```
documents = new DataList(JSON.parse(loaded.response)["documents"]);
```

в следствии чего появились ошибки :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

в строке `var status = this.numberOfSelected < this.data.length;` и

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

в строке `if(this.data[element.index].checked)` ну и если "пытаться фиксить" эти моменты - дальше в конструкторе есть еще много "похожего".

Много написал и теперь пришло время вопроса, подскажите пожалуйста как написать правильный конструктор, полагаю я неправильно использую "this.", но перечитав пару раз теорию так и не понял почему.

[RivetsJS - официальный сайт (eng)](http://rivetsjs.com/)
[RivetsJS - статья на хабре с русской адаптацией](https://habrahabr.ru/post/262351/)

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: _JSON.parse(loaded.response)["documents"]_ возвращает _undefined_ строит проверить, какой именно объект получается в результате _JSON.parse(loaded.response)_

Comment: @Grundy попробовал создать массив объектов "вручную", результат тот же. Если не использовать конструктор - все работает (но там дубляж огромный получается) т.к. я три одинаковых объекта описываю. Конструктор для теста :
`function DataTest(kindOf, checked, title) {
    this.kindOf = kindOf;
    this.checked = checked;
    this.title = "Awesome book " + title;
}`
Создаем : `var data = [];  
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
        data[i] = new DataTest(0, false, "Cool Author");  
    }`  
Создаем посл. объект :`documents = new DataList(data);`.

Comment: сделай [mcve]. Без него можно только сказать, что ты передаешь _undefined_ и получаешь соответствующую ошибку

Comment: @grundy немного разобрался с "проблемой", все дело в облсати видимости. Метод, который я описал в конструкторе, вызывается с помощью rivets при клике на checkBox, после вызова в методе перестают быть доступны все данные с класса, что были описаны выше.  
 `<li rv-each-item="documents.data">  
       <label>  
       <input type="checkbox" rv-checked="item.checked" rv-on-change="documents.updateNumberOfSelected"/>  
       </label>  
</li>`  
Можно ли как-то заставить "видеть" этот метод нужные мне данные, что описываются в том же конструкторе?

Comment: _Можно ли как-то заставить "видеть" этот метод нужные мне данные, что описываются в том же конструкторе?_ - без [mcve] ничего нельзя сказать. Пока непонятно что за _rivets_ и как он используется

Comment: [более детально все расписал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563003/js-constructor-rivets)

Comment: стоило отредактировать данный вопрос, а не создавать новый, к тому же на тот вопрос - тот же ответ: передается _undefined_ вот и получаешь ошибку. Ну и я так и не понял что такое _rivets_

Comment: да, стоило бы. Второй день пользуюсь этим ресурсом и еще не освоился. rivetsJS это библиотека.

Comment: добавь ссылку на нее в вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44958/discussion-between-phobophobia-and-grundy).

Comment: @Grundy done. В конец статьи добавил. Не думал, что кто-то, кто с этим раньше не встречался, захочет в этом разбираться.